# Implement Objective C code in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to handle the pressing of the back button on a UI Navigation bar. I have an extension in objective C (https://github.com/onegray/UIViewController-BackButtonHandler) and i have bridged it to my project in Swift using the header, now I do not quite know how to implement the code in Swift. This is the implementation in C:

```
-(BOOL) navigationShouldPopOnBackButton {
if(needsShowConfirmation) {
    // Show confirmation alert
    // ...
    return NO; // Ignore 'Back' button this time
}
return YES; // Process 'Back' button click and Pop view controler
```

}

Comment: can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func navigationShouldPopOnBackButton() -> Bool {
        if(needsShowConfirmation) {
            // Show confirmation alert
            // ...
            return false // Ignore 'Back' button this time
        }
        return true // Process 'Back' button click and Pop view controller
    }
```